# Can I have a type assertion on the left hand side of an assignment in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript docs talk about type assertions, but apparently they can only be used in expressions, while I'd need to assert the type of a variable on the left hand side of an assignment.

My specific situation is an express middleware that extends the `req` object with a `user` property:

```js
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  req.user = user; // Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'.
  // ...
});
```

I know that I can just reassign the variable, but that seems a little clumsy:

```js
interface AuthenticationRequest extends Request {
    user: string;
}

const myReq = <AuthenticationRequest>req;

myReq = user;
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: `(req as AuthenticationRequest).user = user`. Or, if that assertion is not allowed, `(req as unknown as AuthenticationRequest).user = user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a type assertion on the left hand side, the syntax is exactly the same as a type assertion used anywhere else:

```
declare const user: string;
declare const req: Request

(req as AuthenticationRequest).user = user;

interface AuthenticationRequest extends Request {
    user: string;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I tried this: `<AuthenticationRequest>req.user = user;`, but it failed with a syntax error, I didn't think to try with parentheses. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `(<AuthenticationRequest>req).user = user;` should work as well you just need the extra  `()`

Comment: I realize it'd be really silly and probably specific to the problems created by express middlewares, but you wouldn't happen to be able to just redeclare variables/function parameters with a different type, would you?

Comment: @AndrewPeterPrifer You can specify the parameter type to use `app.use(async (req: AuthenticationRequest , res, next) => {` but if that works depends if you have `strictFunctionTypes` on or off (it will work with off)

Comment: Yes, I have `strictFunctionTypes` enabled and I was hesitant to turn it off just for this case ;)

Comment: @AndrewPeterPrifer You could use a type assertion on the whole function (`app.use(async (req: AuthenticationRequest , res, next) => { ...} as express.NextFunction` although you loose some type checking with regard to param types. Or augment `app.use` which is overkill if this is a single use case. OR augment `Express.Request` if this is a property added by middleware and is widely available ..

Comment: Yeah I considered all of these and they all seem a bit overkill. Thankfully these are just hypotheticals for now, my immediate problem is solved. Thanks again!